# Google Places consuming from REST not filtering by desired type

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

I'm consuming a result from the REST API of Google Places, so far this is what Google Maps tell me about the nearest places around me

[image]

Now, I'm using this URL to query my results

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=lat,long&radius=50&type=restaurantkeyword=restaurant&key=MY_API_KEY
```

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types), I'm using the correct `type =` to filter my query.

I'm filtering by type restaurant with a radios of 50 meters; now, the result that the rest provides to me is this:

[image]

Where you can see that the results showing here are not for the type restaurant, but instead it searches for all `establishments` as the FAQ says

> Why are some places not returned when I filter by type? It's possible
>   that the place you are looking for has not yet been categorized. All
>   places are categorized as the generic type "establishment" until
>   Google has enough data about a place to categorize it as one of the
>   supported place types.
>
> As a workaround you can pass the place type to the keyword parameter.
>   The keyword parameter is matched to: name, type, address, and customer
>   reviews.
>
> If you would like to add the category type to a place listing
>   yourself, submit a place edit. Once the edit has been approved and
>   published it will appear using the correct type filtering.

But the problem is that indeed in Google Maps it appears to be restaurants near me, but the query just return all the establishments around me.

Is there a way to fix that response in order to just return the restaurants near me and not all the places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url query has bug. You need to insert an '&' between restaurant and keyword. I tested with the below query and it looks correct:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-31.41668,-64.1909&radius=50&type=restaurant&keyword=restaurant&key=MY_API_KEY
```

Comment: oh wow, since the response had values on it and not errors in the success key i was like " there is no way that the link is wrong " thanks in advanced !